# facebook feed used only android web browser error fired

Tags: android, facebook, callback, feed, facebook-feed

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true
        });
    };      
    function postToFeed (){
        var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'https://www.xxxxx.kr/',
            picture: 'https://www.xxxxx.kr/banner-1.jpg',
            name: 'xxx',
            caption: 'https://www.xxxxx.kr/',
            description: 'bbbb'
        };

        function callback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 

<a href="javascript:postToFeed();">[feed]</a><br>
```

This is my source
I have one problem 
This source is not only with the Android Browser

chrome open - [feed] click - white browser open Right away close - callback function run - console.log(response) - response==undefined

i don't know help me